# Azure Devops VSTEST Error: The process 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe' failed with exit code 1

Tags: selenium, azure-devops, vstest

I am having an error in the dotnet Core step

I am trying to integrate my selenium test to Azure devops

[image: This is my dotnet step settings]

This the logs of the dot net step

```
2020-10-16T03:11:25.7523865Z ##[section]Starting: Run Selenium
2020-10-16T03:11:25.8123424Z ==============================================================================
2020-10-16T03:11:25.8124047Z Task         : .NET Core
2020-10-16T03:11:25.8124510Z Description  : Build, test, package, or publish a dotnet application, or run a custom dotnet command
2020-10-16T03:11:25.8124816Z Version      : 2.175.0
2020-10-16T03:11:25.8125178Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2020-10-16T03:11:25.8125636Z Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/dotnet-core-cli
2020-10-16T03:11:25.8126003Z ==============================================================================
2020-10-16T03:11:27.2023831Z [command]C:\windows\system32\chcp.com 65001
2020-10-16T03:11:27.2216959Z Active code page: 65001
2020-10-16T03:11:27.2376255Z Info: .NET Core SDK/runtime 2.2 and 3.0 are now End of Life(EOL) and have been removed from all hosted agents. If you're using these SDK/runtimes on hosted agents, kindly upgrade to newer versions which are not EOL, or else use UseDotNet task to install the required version.
2020-10-16T03:11:27.3059263Z [command]"C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" vstest "D:\a\r1\a\_SeleniumDemo-ASP.NET Core-CI (5)\drop\Demo2.dll" --logger:trxlogfilename=TEST.xml
2020-10-16T03:11:34.8402885Z 
2020-10-16T03:11:34.9823477Z Welcome to .NET Core 3.1!
2020-10-16T03:11:34.9824051Z ---------------------
2020-10-16T03:11:34.9824560Z SDK Version: 3.1.402
2020-10-16T03:11:34.9824775Z 
2020-10-16T03:11:34.9836054Z Telemetry
2020-10-16T03:11:34.9836648Z ---------
2020-10-16T03:11:34.9838913Z The .NET Core tools collect usage data in order to help us improve your experience. The data is anonymous. It is collected by Microsoft and shared with the community. You can opt-out of telemetry by setting the DOTNET_CLI_TELEMETRY_OPTOUT environment variable to '1' or 'true' using your favorite shell.
2020-10-16T03:11:34.9840343Z 
2020-10-16T03:11:34.9840938Z Read more about .NET Core CLI Tools telemetry: https://aka.ms/dotnet-cli-telemetry
2020-10-16T03:11:34.9841242Z 
2020-10-16T03:11:34.9841449Z ----------------
2020-10-16T03:11:34.9841756Z Explore documentation: https://aka.ms/dotnet-docs
2020-10-16T03:11:34.9842152Z Report issues and find source on GitHub: https://github.com/dotnet/core
2020-10-16T03:11:34.9842572Z Find out what's new: https://aka.ms/dotnet-whats-new
2020-10-16T03:11:34.9842993Z Learn about the installed HTTPS developer cert: https://aka.ms/aspnet-core-https
2020-10-16T03:11:34.9843479Z Use 'dotnet --help' to see available commands or visit: https://aka.ms/dotnet-cli-docs
2020-10-16T03:11:34.9843894Z Write your first app: https://aka.ms/first-net-core-app
2020-10-16T03:11:34.9844375Z --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2020-10-16T03:11:39.1360071Z Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 16.7.0
2020-10-16T03:11:39.1368990Z Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
2020-10-16T03:11:39.1369374Z 
2020-10-16T03:11:40.1936906Z The Test Logger URI 'trxlogfilename=TEST.xml' is not valid.  The Test Logger will be ignored.
2020-10-16T03:11:40.7284653Z ##[error]Error: The process 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe' failed with exit code 1
2020-10-16T03:11:40.8737953Z Info: Azure Pipelines hosted agents have been updated to contain .Net Core 3.x (3.1) SDK/Runtime along with 2.1. Unless you have locked down a SDK version for your project(s), 3.x SDK might be picked up which might have breaking behavior as compared to previous versions. 
2020-10-16T03:11:40.8738674Z Some commonly encountered changes are: 
2020-10-16T03:11:40.8740232Z If you're using `Publish` command with -o or --Output argument, you will see that the output folder is now being created at root directory rather than Project File's directory. To learn about more such changes and troubleshoot, refer here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/dotnet-core-cli?view=azure-devops#troubleshooting
2020-10-16T03:11:40.8747693Z ##[error]Dotnet command failed with non-zero exit code on the following projects : D:\a\r1\a\_SeleniumDemo-ASP.NET Core-CI (5)\drop\Demo2.dll
2020-10-16T03:11:40.8951889Z ##[section]Finishing: Run Selenium
```

I tried to run my code using my local machine and got not error. Please help me with Azure integration

Comment: `The Test Logger URI 'trxlogfilename=TEST.xml' is not valid.  The Test Logger will be ignored.`. Your agent missing `TEST.xml` file. You also could try to use the `Visual Studio Test` task?

Comment: if below answer resolved your question, you could [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), so it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks.

Comment: Hi, Just checking in to see whether this issue is still blocking you now? Any update for this issue?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Thanks for the solution you provided! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can reproduce this issue with the same configuration, and then I change the argument to `--logger:"trx;Logfilename=TEST.trx"`  and it works.

[image]

Result:

[image]